# Subfolders in share not available until I open them

Tags: samba, thunar, smb

I've been testing Duplicati to back my user directory to a Windows 10 share and I noticed an odd behavior.

If I just let Duplicati do its thing, after a while the subfolders in the target location are not accessible. I then just open Thunar, navigate to that subfolder, then try Duplicati, and it works again.

It's like my system only wants to see the top level directories of the share after a bit of time. I have to navigate into subfolders to make other utilities work.

I noticed similar problems outside of Duplicati. There's a little hesitation to enter a directory the first time, then it's good for a while.

Is there some sort of timeout in play here with the SMB shares and subfolders?

Comment: How exactly are you mounting the SMB share(s)?

Comment: I'm mounting the SMB shares through fstab as follows:    

  
`//192.168.0.100/user /mnt/user cifs vers=3.0,username=username,password=password,noperm,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,iocharset=utf8,_netdev,cache=none 0 0`